# why container object in pod yaml file has "list value" rather than a "map value"

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, containers, kubernetes-pod

In the pod creation yaml files or in the deployment yaml files in kubernetes, why Containers key has a list value `- name: memory-demo-ctr` rather than we can simply provide the map value `name: memory-demo-ctr` (why we're providing `-` symbol)?

I tried looking at over the web but couldn't find a solution.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: memory-demo
  namespace: mem-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: memory-demo-ctr
    image: polinux/stress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pod is capable of running multiple containers. That's the reason `containers` object is a list instead of map.

```
kind: Pod
...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox:latest
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.7.9
  - name: redis
    image: redis:latest
```

If `containers` is a map object, you cannot write a configuration file to run multiple containers inside a pod. I hope this answer solved your doubt.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense

Comment: @Teja please upvote/accept the answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The use of both mentioned structures in **kubernetes yaml manifests** is quite well justified and if you take a closer look, it becomes also quite intuitive:

`Maps` (aka `Dictionaries`) *are used when providing a set of `key: value` pairs.* Please note that the keys are unique in one such set e.g. you provide different set of `labels` in `metadata` section of your `Deployment` definition. `metadata` element is also in a form of `Dictionary` as it contains a set of unique keys ( `name` and `labels` in this particular case).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
    type: front-end
```

Just to give one more example, let's take a look at the `spec` section. Note that all three keys that are children of the `spec` element, namely `replicas`, `selector` and `template`, are unique in the whole set and that's the reason they are in a form of a `Dictionary` ( or a `Map` ):

```
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
```

`Lists` (aka `Arrays`) *are used when we need to provide a `List` (or `Array`) of objects/elements of the same type* like in case of `containers` in `Deployment` definition:

```
containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

`container` element is an array as it may contain many objects/elements/items of the same type ( in this case containers ) which can have same properties. In `container` section you can define many containers and each of them will have its unique `name`, `image` and `ports`. `-` sign *indicates one element or item of the array*. Note that the structure inside such element element is a `Map` (`Dictionary`) and as in the previous examples it contains *set of unique keys* with corresponding values.

The use of these two structures is quite flexible as they can be nested within one another e.g. you can have a `Lists` of `Dictionaries` ( as in case of `containers` ), `Dictionaries` which values are other `Dictionaries` as well as `Dictionaries` containing `Lists`, to exhaust all possibilities ( example of such case is `spec` element which is a `Dictionary` which among others contains `containers` key which is a list ( value of this `key` is a `list/array` of `items` ).

---

As to your specific question:

> why Containers key has a list value - name: memory-demo-ctr rather
>   than we can simply provide the map value name: memory-demo-ctr (why
>   we're providing - symbol)?

Note that a list value ( list item ) for the `container` key is not only the `name` element but the whole structure at the same indentation level under the `container`. As I already mentioned above, one list item is indicated by `-` sign. In the example posted in your question keys `name` and `image` with their respective values belong to the same element/item of a `list` (`array`) and they form another nested `dictionary` (`map`). So it's not the `name` element that must be preceded by `-` character but the whole structure ( in this case `Dictionary/Map` ) under `container` element. When you define another container (another item of container list) it always starts with another `-` character, no matter if the first element within it is `name`. For example you can construct your structure like this and it will also be correct:

```
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.7.9
  - image: redis
    name: redis
  - command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo Hello Kubernetes! && sleep 3600']
    image: busybox
    name: myapp-container
```

The `dictionary` (`map`) elements do not have to appear in the same order. It's just a convention that `name` is usually placed as the first one. **I will emphasize it again:** these are not `name`, `image` and `command` in the above example that are items of a list but the whole `dictionary` (`map`) structure preceded by `-` character, so these are:

first:

```
- name: nginx
  image: nginx:1.7.9
```

second:

```
- image: redis
  name: redis
```

and third:

```
- command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo Hello Kubernetes! && sleep 3600']
  image: busybox
  name: myapp-container
```

`items`/`elements` of the `containers` list (which at the same time is one of the `keys` belonging to `spec` dictionary). Yes, the value of this `key` is a `list` so we can say that the whole `containers` element is a list.

I hope it clarified the usage of both structures and explained the differences between them.

Comment: Thank you mario for a very detailed explanation, appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If the answer was helpful and/or provided solution to your problem, you can consider accepting it and/or voting on it. As a new member of the Community you can familiarize with this short article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You have a list value in containers because a pod can be composed of multiple containers.

A pod represents the smallest building block in kubernetes.
Instead of deploying containers individually you allways deploy and operate on a pod of containers.

The key thing about pods is that when a pod contains multiple containers, all of them are always run on a single worker node, it never spans multiple worker nodes.